# To use py26-markdown installed by MacPorts

Tags: macos, macports, markdown

I installed the following Markdown-to-HTML converter by MacPorts.

```
py26-markdown @2.0 (python, textproc)
    Python implementation of Markdown
```

I run

```
py26-markdown 1.markdown
```

I get

```
zsh: command not found: py26-markdown
```

**How can you use py26-markdown?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`py26-markdown` is not the program's name, it's the name of the package.  The program is `markdown.py` and it comes from that package. It's a module you use by importing it into Python, or by running it from the command line.  [Using it from the command-line](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Command_Line) is explained in the user's guide.  It looks like this:

```
<python> markdown.py input_file.txt > output_file.html
```

You may need to explicitly call it from Python depending on whether it is executable by default or not.

To find out where the actual script lives you should ask port:

```
port contents py26-markdown | grep markdown.py
```

markdown.py doesn't necessarily need to be on your PATH, but it will be a lot easier to use it lives in your PYTHONPATH, which should include /opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your `$PATH` variable wasn't set properly, or was only set for `bash`. Make sure it contains `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin` and that `$MANPATH` contains `/opt/local/share/man`.

**Edit:** Actually, wait, is py26-markdown even supposed to be a command? [This page](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Installation) suggests it may be something you use from *within* Python.